# Stop permutations function after certain number of permutations are generated

Tags: r, dplyr, combinations, permutation, bioinformatics

I am using this script below to generate all possible permutations of a length of 15 from a list of 20 amino acids.

test <- permutations(20, 15, all.amino.acids)

There are soooo many different permutations, so I am trying to figure out a way to stop this function once its generated a certain number of outputs. Nothing I've tried works, any ideas?

Comment: which library's `permutations` (that you might list above) are you using, I have from `admisc`, `vegan`, `e1071` (but none use your three position function input). To show your code, put three backtics , end of code, three more, and you get that 'code look'. A thing you could try, in the face of sooo many, `...all.amino.acids)[100]`, to see if you get 100 in test...And welcome to Stackoverflow.

Comment: Have a look at `RcppAlgos` package, `permuteSample` looks relevant